# Dynamically inject the current date into PostgreSQL query with copy export

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Is there a way I can dynamically inject the date in YYYYMMDD format into this PostgreSQL query that I am using with `copy` inside `psql`?

```
copy (SELECT 
        course.id, course.area, course.status, course.type, 
        customer.firstname, customer.lastname, customer.email 
      FROM course 
      JOIN customer_course 
      ON customer_course.course_id = course.id 
      JOIN customer 
      ON customer.id = customer_course.customer_id 
      WHERE course.type LIKE '%heathland%' 
      AND course.status = 'open'
    ) TO '~/Dropbox/CRMPicco/prod-customer-courses-' . (SELECT NOW()::date) . '.csv' WITH CSV;
```

When I run that query I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: ...ace%' AND course.status = 'open' ) TO STDOUT . (SELECT ...
```

It would be advantageous if I could create this CSV with the current date without having to manually edit the query.

Comment: Are you running this in `psql`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I should've mentioned that in the original question. I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

In `psql` you can set a variable to the name of the output file:

```
postgres=#> select '~/Dropbox/CRMPicco/prod-customer-courses-'||current_date||'.csv' as fname
postgres=#> \gset
postgres=#> copy (...) to :'fname';
```

Note the missing `;` after the first select, you have to terminate that statement with  `\gset`. The variable name is defined through the column alias of the "source".

Comment: Thanks for this. Is it possible to do on a single line? When I attempt to run it on a single line I get about 20-30 errors similar to `\gset: extra argument "(SELECT" ignored`

Comment: @crmpicco: no, `\gset` requires a separate query